# Apollo Graphql when refreshing token doesn't update useQuery

Tags: reactjs, graphql, jwt, next.js, apollo

I'm facing next problem:
I have a useQuery hook for getting usersData

#### GET_USER_INFO useQuery

```
const { data:dataGetUserInfo, loading:loadingQuery, error:errorQuery,refetch  } = useQuery(GET_USER_INFO, {variables: {
            getUserInfoInfoId: userId
        }});
```

And I want to refresh access and refresh tokens when access token is expired. For that I've done errorLink in apollo-client.ts which calls a refesh fucntion when it needs to and then recall my GET_USER_INFO useQuery

#### apollo-client.ts

```
const getNewToken =  () => {
    let refreshToken

        refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("REFRESH");

    return client.mutate({
        mutation: REFRESH_TOKEN,
        variables:{
            refreshTokenRefreshToken : refreshToken,
        }
    })
        .then((res) => {
            localStorage.clear();
            const { accessToken,refreshToken } = res.data.refreshToken;
            localStorage.setItem('REFRESH',refreshToken)
            localStorage.setItem('AUTHORIZATION',accessToken)
            return res.data;
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
            
        })

};



const errorLink = onError(
    ({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
        if (graphQLErrors) {
            for (let err of graphQLErrors) {

                switch (err.extensions?.code) {
                    
                    case "UNAUTHENTICATED" :
                        console.log('aa')
                        return fromPromise(
                            getNewToken().catch((error) => {
                                localStorage.clear();
                                // Handle token refresh errors e.g clear stored tokens, redirect to login
                                return;
                            })
                        )
                            .filter((value) => Boolean(value))
                            .flatMap(({accessToken, refreshToken}) => {

                                const oldHeaders = operation.getContext().headers;
                                // modify the operation context with a new token
                                operation.setContext({
                                    headers: {
                                        ...oldHeaders,
                                        authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                                    },
                                });

                                // retry the request, returning the new observable
                                return forward(operation);
                            });
                   

                }
            }
        }
    }
);



const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: localStorage.getItem("AUTHORIZATION") ? `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("AUTHORIZATION")}` : "",
    },
  };
});




const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink,authLink, httpLink]),
})
```

**The problem is:**
it doesn't refetch data in my useQuery after successfull refreshing tokens

[image: 2 query]

[image: 4 query]

btw it does one more failing request i don't know why

[image: 3 query]

Comment: You need to use useLazyQuery . For eg. you have a component where you call useQuery, then as soon as the component mounts, useQuery runs and the data is fetched from the server. But if you use useLazyQuery in that component instead of useQuery, query doesn't run and data isn't fetched when component mounts. Instead you can run the query based on your requirement, say after you got refresh token or on clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [retry link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-retry/) to run the query again.

You should chain your links in a way that the retry link is the most outer link so that you can wait for your error link to fetch the token. Check out the [custom strategies](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-retry/#custom-strategies), here you could react to a specific status code in the error object or listen to a custom property, that the error link could attach to the `operation` object. This way you can even prevent a refetch if the token refresh failed (e.g. because the refetch token also timed out).

The links are also all open source so if chaining them doesn't really work for you, you could also develop your own refetch+retry link by combining the code of both links.